# how to correct the orientation of the image with ITK-VTK

Tags: vtk, itk

I am a beginner in VTK ITK, I am trying to read a DICOM series with ITK and display with VTK but I had pictures upside down, I tried to read a single image (JPG) with ITK and visualuser with VTK it is the same problem, so I had the idea of ​​treating the image on photoshop ie I applied to the original image rotation (vertical symmetry of the work area) and I did the reading with ITK and display with VTK, the image is displayed in the correct orientation, infact ITK keeps the orientation of the image, but the problem is at VTK, it is which displays the image upside down, I searched all over the internet I have not found a solution or a method or not even an idea, I encountered the same problem in many forums but there is no response, I count on your help, I can not apply any image processing to find a solution to this problem.

Please Help! thank you in advance

Comment: Why not just read using VTK and not ITK?  vtkJPEGReader will do the trick.  If your set on using ITK and still have this problem, you could always reverse the image by iterating through each voxel value starting at 0,0,0 and setting the values to i-1,j-1,0.  You can do this by converting the image to vtkImageData before displaying.

Comment: I have to read a DICOM series with ITK because I need segmentation techniques, and I use vtk for visualization. Please can you explain me with an example.thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should re-orient your camera in VTK so that it is suited for medical image visualization. (The default camera in VTK uses the computer graphics conventions).

If you want a quick hack, you can copy-paste the following code in ITK:

```
    FlipFilterType::Pointer flipperImage = FlipFilterType::New();
bool flipAxes[3] = { false, true, false };
flipperImage = FlipFilterType::New();
flipperImage->SetFlipAxes(flipAxes);
flipperImage->SetInput( image );
flipperImage->Update();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, here is my code on this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109610/how-to-connect-itk-to-vtk-with-c?rq=1. please where I added this code? thank you

Comment: thank you very much, I used this method and it works very well :)

Comment: Please, how can I close the question, is this just click to toggle?

Answer (score 2):

I use a rapid way to set the orientation:

`imageActor->SetOrientation(180,0,0);`

No need to add filter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I would do it.  I'm not sure what classes you are using, so I cannot be specific.

```
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> result = vtkSmartPointer<vtkIMageData>::New();
    result->DeepCopy(YourImage);  //DeepCopy your image to result
    rImage->Update();

    double val;
    int i = 0;

    for(vtkIdType f = result->GetNumberOfPoints()-1; f > -1; f--)
    {
      val = YourImage->GetPointData()->GetScalars()->GetTuple1(f);
      result->GetPointData()->GetScalars->SetTuple1(i,val);
      i++;
    }



result->Update();
//Now Visualize your image
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, well, I use vtkImageViewer2.h, here is my code on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109610/how-to-connect-itk-to-vtk-with-c?rq=1

Comment: I'm sorry for my question, I am a beginner in ITK VTK, is  it possible to convert vtkImageViewer2 to vtkImageData ?

Comment: I believe so. Something like this:  `vtkImageData *ImageData = YourVtkImageViewerObject->GetInput();`